# Facebook batch calls with JSONP

Tags: facebook, api, batch-file, jsonp

As of 10.04.2012, 
There is a short paragraph in the [Facebook developer document for 'batch request'](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) entitled: **Batch calls with JSONP**, which reads:

```
"The Batch API supports JSONP, just like the rest of the Graph API - 
 the JSONP callback function is specified using the 'callback' query string 
 or form post parameter."
```

I thought that meant you can also do a batch request using JSONP from Javascript (which will be a GET request, as JSONP works only as a GET request), so I tried that, with adding a 'batch' parameter (containing objects describing requests for batch as in the doc) to the query string. 
Response from FB server was:

```
Only POST is allowed for batch requests
```

So, questions: 
 1. What did they mean in that paragraph? 
 2. Is there a way to do an asynchronous batch request from Javascript?

Comment: Can you share the code you used which ended with that response?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same. Sample code is

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;     
var AjaxRequest = jQuery.ajax( {
  url: "http://graph.facebook.com/",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  data: { "access_token": AccessToken, "batch": BatchRequest },
  dataType: "jsonp",
  error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
    ... show error stuff
    },
  success: function( Return, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    showLog( "Return " + JSON.stringify( Return ) );
    showLog( "textStatus " + textStatus );
    showLog( "jqXHR " + JSON.stringify( jqXHR ) );
    if ( Return.error ) {
      ... go away
      }
    else {
      ... use the data
      }
    }
  } ); // eo ajax request
```

which gives

```
Return {"error":3,"error_description":"Only POST is allowed for batch requests"}
textStatus success
jqXHR {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}
```

i.e. it successfully sends back an error message. JSONP translates the POST type to a GET, which Facebook doesn't support...

To answer qu.2 you can use FB.api to do asynchronous batch request in javascript. I was trying out JSONP because IE8 keeps hanging on the return from Facebook with FB.api.